# Pin Configuration for Breadboard 3.5mm Stereo Audio Jack

Tags: audio, breadboard

I have this 3.5 mm [stereo audio jack](http://ph.rs-online.com/web/p/jack-trs-connectors/5130421/) which can be mounted on a breadboard.
Could someone please help me with the pin configuration?

I'm using this audio jack to serve as input to the MT8870 DTMF Decoder.
Here's the circuit diagram:
[image]

Comment: The pinout for that connector is in its datasheet, which is linked from that page at RS.  Have you found that?  http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/12ac/0900766b812ac664.pdf

Comment: as of 2018, the linked page is https://docs-apac.rs-online.com/webdocs/12ac/0900766b812ac664.pdf but both links work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the datasheet, you will see a wiring diagram.  This wiring diagram uses [audio jack notation (tip,ring,sleeve)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Design) so what you want to do is connect pin 1 from your audio jack to ground and pin 2 or 5 as input to the CM8770. One for left and right channels. Pin 2 and 4 on the audio jack is the audio signal you're feeding to the jack via an aux cable, so they don't really matter in this case.

Comment: Hi, noob here,but I think there's a typo since you mention pin 2 twice. While 2 and 5 are indeed input, the "aux" signal uses pins 3 and 4, not "2 and 4" (and is disconnected when the plug is inserted). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

From the dimensions given in the datasheet, I don't think that connector will fit in the usual platic breadboard - and I think it unlikely that you'll find a version that will fit a breadboard. The connector is designed for use in a custom PC board, where the board designer will place pin holes as required to fit the connector.

You would have to solder wires to the connector pins, and plug those wires into the breadboard.

Comment: Agreed, it won't fit in breadboard. This one does: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1699